# Panda gem and heroku

Tags: file-upload, heroku, pandastream

I've tried following the instructions here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pandastream

However, when I open up the heroku console and run the command:

```
video = Panda::Video.create(:source_url => "http://panda-test-harness-videos.s3.amazonaws.com/panda.mp4")
```

I've tried adding lots of dynos with:

```
heroku dynos 100
```

However I still get the following error from Heroku:

```
Your application is too busy to open a console session.
Console sessions require an open dyno to use for execution.
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Cheers,

Richard

Comment: Contact Heroku support - there is nothing wrong with what you are doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems more like a problem with Heroku not having setup your app yet, or some other underlying problem.

I have no trouble with this, so write them, and ask what's up :)